# Question on matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A$ be a real matrix with real eigenvalues $\lambda_k$ and complex eigenvalues
$\alpha_ k \pm i\omega_ k$ , all of which are simple. I'm trying to show that every element of the matrix $e^ {tA}$ is a linear combination of the functions $e^ {λ_ k t} , e^ {α _k t} \cos ω _k t, e^ {α_ k t} \sin ω_ k t$. How do I do this?

Comment: Three key steps are: Jordan Canonical Form, the exponent of black-diagonal matrix and some simple calculations for simple blocks of JCF.

Comment: Since they are simple eigenvalues, you don't need JCF: the matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Pardon me, but diagonal form **is** a complex JCF for this case :) And OP is clearly interested in real solutions of system, so it might be good to stick to real JCF, which isn't diagonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two pieces of information to do this problem:

Let $\exp(tA)$ denote the matrix exponential.  We note that
$$
\exp \left[t\pmatrix{d_1\\&\ddots \\ &&d_n}\right] = 
{}{}\pmatrix{e^{d_1t}\\&\ddots\\&& e^{d_nt}}
$$

that is, we have an explicit formula for the exponential of a diagonal matrix.  Furthermore, for any invertible matrix $S$ and any matrix $A$, we have
$$
\exp[SAS^{-1}t] = S\exp[At]S^{-1}    
$$

Now, note that your matrix $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If you like differential equations, then you can approach the subject that way, even for the most general matrix $A$. For example, if $D$ is the differential operator $\frac{d}{dt}$, then the general solution of
$$
                   (D-\lambda_1)^{n_1}(D-\lambda_2)^{n_2}(\cdots)(D-\lambda_{k})^{n_{k}}f=0
$$
is well-known to be
$$
               (a_{1,0}+a_{1,1}x+\cdots+a_{1,n_1-1}x^{n_1-1})e^{\lambda_{1}t}\\
              +(a_{2,0}+a_{2,1}x+\cdots+a_{2,n_2-1}x^{n_2-1})e^{\lambda_{2}t}\\
                            + \cdots  +\\
              +(1_{k,0}+a_{k,1}x+\cdots+a_{k,n_k-1}x^{n_k-1})e^{\lambda_{k}t}.
$$
In the special case that $n_1=n_2=\cdots=n_k=1$, the general solution is
$$
              f = a_1 e^{\lambda_1 t}+a_2e^{\lambda_2 t}+\cdots+a_k e^{\lambda_k t}.
$$
**How this applies:**
It may not be immediately obvious that this applies. However,
$$
               \frac{d}{dt}e^{tA} = Ae^{tA},\;\;\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}e^{tA}=A^{2}e^{tA},\cdots.
$$
Therefore, if $m(\lambda)=(\lambda-\lambda_1)^{n_1}(\lambda-\lambda_2)^{n_2}\cdots(\lambda-\lambda_k)^{n_k}$ is the minimal polynomial for $A$, then
$$
                m(D)e^{tA} = m(A)e^{tA}=0.
$$
That means that every component function $f_{j,k}(t)$ of the matrix $[f_{j,k}(t)]=e^{tA}$ satisfies the differentiation equation
$$
                           m(D)f_{j,k}(t) = 0.
$$
This works for any matrix $A$. In particular, if $A$ has a minimal polynomial with linear factors only, then the matrix entries must be linear combinations of exponentials $e^{\lambda_{j}t}$ where $\lambda_j$ are the eigenvalues. Of course, if $\lambda_{j}=\alpha_{j}+i\beta_{j}$ where $\alpha_{j}$, $\beta_{j}$ are real, then
$$
           e^{\lambda_{j}t} = e^{-\beta_{j}t}(\cos(\alpha_{j}t)+i\sin(\alpha_{j}t)).
$$

Answer (score 0):

we need to use the fact that $A$ can be diagonalized by a change of variable  $x = Sy$ so that $S^{-1}AS$ is a diagonal matrix with single blocks $\lambda$ for each real eigenvalue $\lambda$ and by a $2 \times 2$ blocks of the form 
$\left( \begin{array}{ll} \alpha & -\omega \cr \omega & \alpha\end{array} \right).$

we will take $e^{At}x(0)$ as the unique solution to the initial value problem $\frac{dx}{dt} = Ax$ subject to the initial condition $x = x(0)$ at time $t = 0$
is transformed into solving the decoupled systems of the form
$\frac{dy}{dt} = \lambda y$ whose solution is $e^{\lambda_k t}y(0)$ and 
for each complex eigenvalue $\alpha \pm i\omega,$ you can write two coupled equations $\frac{dx}{dt} = \alpha x - \omega y$ and $\frac{dy}{dt} = \omega x - \alpha y$ whose solutions are 
$\left( \begin{array}{l} x \cr y \end{array} \right) = e^{\alpha_kt}\left(\begin{array}{ll} \alpha & -\omega \cr \omega & \alpha \end{array} \right) \left(\begin{array}{l} x(0) \cr y(0) \end{array} \right).$

now, you can transform back to the original variable $x$ where each component of $x$ which is a linear combination of all the components of $y$.

from these solutions you can construct the fundamental solutions as a linear combinations of these.